# How to link and package external library with node-gyp for electron

Tags: linker, electron, tesseract, node-gyp, n-api

I created [a native OCR module](https://github.com/stoefln/node-native-ocr) using N-API ([node-addon-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-addon-api)) with bindings to tesseract OCR.

My intention is to get native OCR working under electron. I basically checked all the npm packages related to OCR and they all don't work with electron. And here is my own test project
based on electron, which uses my node-native-ocr module:
https://github.com/stoefln/electron-ocr

My problem:
I don't manage to package all the dependencies when bundling electron. Or there seems to be a problem with the way I do it, because I am currently getting this error when running the electron project in production:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _fmemopen   Referenced from: /Volumes/Shared
> Folders/Downloads/Electron
> OCR.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/node-native-ocr/build/Release/dependencies/liblept.5.dylib
> Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

The way I am currently trying to package: The .node file which is generated depends on tesseract (built with brew) which depends on a lot of other libraries installed on the system.
What I came up with is [a script](https://github.com/stoefln/electron-ocr/blob/main/scripts/fixDylibs.js) which recursively reads dependencies (`otool -l`), copies them into the .node folder and changes the link (`install_name_tool -change ...`) to point to the copied dylib file.

I am not even sure if that's the right way of doing it. Shouldn't the node-gyp linker take care of linking AND packaging everything?
Here is somebody asking basically the same question: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/2258

---

**More information if you want to reproduce my problem**:

1. Run `npm run export-mac`
2. Copy the .app file to some other machine, to make sure it does not use the libararies in the system and only the ones which are packaged.
3. Start the app via the command line (otherwise you won't see the error): `./your_path_to_the_app_file/Electron\ OCR.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron\ OCR`
4. Click the single button in the UI and check the terminal output

Comment: can you specify the path the to the static .a file in the "libraries" section. 
  "libraries": [ "/usr/local/lib/mylib.a" ]

Comment: @RakshaSaini the instruction in node gyp `pkg-config tesseract --libs` already returns the path to the library. In fact, if I execute this line in the terminal, it returns `-L/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/lib -ltesseract -lcurl`. Don't know if this is correct.